# Azure Functions - Switching NodeJS to .Net Core and keep URL

Tags: azure-functions

I want to replace an Azure Function written in Typescript to .Net Core 3.1.

Is it possible to do that and still keep the URL of my old function?

I'm using the URL in desktop applications and would like to avoid having to update them as well if possible.

Comment: not sure if you can repurpose an existing function. But if you just delete your existing function and immediately you recreate a new Function with the same name, chances of not being able to get the same name are very slim.

Comment: I'm thinking more about the "code" parameter part. I don't feel confident that will stay the same...

Comment: you mean the function key? You can simply add a new key in the new function and supply the old key

Comment: But if I change the key the URL changes and I need to redeploy my applications with the new URL

Comment: I just said that you can create a new key and supply a custom value. There you supply the value of your current key

Comment: Oh, sorry! missed that part. I'll check it out

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I haven't had time to work on it since I wrote the question. I'll make sure to update this question when I do.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the url is decided by the name of the function. And the function key can be changed.

You can change it in this place:

[image]

After deploy, go to manage of your function app, then revoke the function key you are using now and add a new one as you want. Don't forget to save the edit.

[image]